# unable to submit form tag in laravel

Tags: laravel

unable to call post URL from form tag. When I click on the submit button it is going to a different URL name viewstudentmarks.

```
<form method="post"  style="padding-top:30px;" action="{{ route('updatestudentmark',['id' => $stuid]) }}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{$examtype}}">
      <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">


                    </div>

            </div>


          </div>

      </div>
    </div>

        @foreach($extra as $detail)
          <a  class="btn btn-success" href='{{ url("viewstudentmarks/{$detail->class_id}") }}'>Back</a>
         @endforeach

               <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
```

and web.php

```
Route::post('updatestudentmark/{id}','MarksRecordController@update')->name('updatestudentmark');

Route::get('viewhealthdetails/{id}','HealthDetailsController@viewstudents')->name('viewhealthdetails');
```

Comment: Add csrf token in your form.

Comment: yes I have added already

Comment: Do you get any debugging errors? It looks like it should work fine.

Comment: I am not getting any error it is going to some other url.

Comment: Why are you passing the $stuid as an array? It should just be a single value like an integer or string.

Comment: try replacing `array($stuid)` with `["id" => $stuid]`.

Comment: and move the route to some upper line which prevents the route to be reached.

Comment: not working bro I already tried that one

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and check your available routes.

Comment: I have pasted full form now If I run it is going to different route you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form tag add `{{ route('') }}` name:

```
<form method="post"  style="padding-top:30px;" action="{{ route('updatestudentmark',['id' => $stuid]) }}">

{{csrf_field()}}

</form>
```

Also, check your controller code. In the controller, Have you call the redirect method or not.

Thanks

Comment: hey this is a get method I need to call post method updatestudentmark/{id}

Comment: @matheenulla I have given just an example. You can able to use a route in the form action

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya op has already used route helper. so why have you answered an example that op already know and does not answer the question.

Comment: @matheenulla I read your all comments. It is redirected to `viewhealthdetails`. Have you to define the redirect method in the `MarksRecordController@update`.??

Comment: @matheenulla Please put your controller  `MarksRecordController@update` method in question.

Comment: @matheenulla But how? Is the issue in controller?

Comment: yes, you are right it was a mistake in the controller. if you were not telling I was sitting for the next 2 hours also. thank you very much.

Comment: @matheenulla Laravel is an MVC framework so alway inspect code in Model, View, and controller.

Answer (score 1):

it's much better to use name routes like:
`Route::post('updatestudentmark/{id}','MarksRecordController@update')->name('test.route');`

and in blade do something like this in action form:
`{{route('test.route',['id' => $stuid])}}`

Comment: Hey now when tried to run it is going to different route wait I will paste full form

Comment: can you share a form and route

Comment: thank for helping it is solve I was made a mistake in the controller

Comment: great. glad to hear that